# LaTeX - Copy and paste º

Tags: copy-paste, lmodern

I have a LaTeX document.

I can copy from PDF (º), but it pastes as (o). How can I handle it?

Use:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern, cmap}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{amssymb}
```

Comment: I don't understand the question. (1) Does your PDF, which you created using LaTeX, contain `(º)` and when you copy-and-paste that, it results in `(o)`? (2) Or does it paste as `(º)` but you want it to paste as `(o)`? (3) Or do you want to know how to create `(º)` that you found in a different PDF, and you're not sure how to create this in LaTeX? Is it (1), (2) or (3)?

Comment: Your "Use:" is also unclear.  It's the beginning of a document, but it doesn't attempt to do anything, (o) or otherwise.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Why copy from a .pdf if you can just use your keyboard? `º` -- and note that not all fonts have the `º` underlined.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to copy and paste to get such simple symbols. I'm not sure what that circle is, but I guess it should be either the functional composition operator,the temperature degree symbol, or the masculine ordinal indicator.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

    \begin{equation*}
    \begin{split}
    f \circ g\\
    \quad \SI{7}{\celsius}\\
    \quad \psi\textsuperscript{\b{x}}
    \end{split}
    \end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Or the masculine ordinal indicator (U+00BA).

Comment: @Thérèse: Thanks for the indication. I've added it to the answer.

Answer (score 9):

The Unicode symbol is U+00BA (MASCULINE ORDINAL INDICATOR).

It is available in encoding TS1 as provided by package `textcomp`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}

\begin{document}
º = \textordmasculine
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Tks \usepackage{textcomp} solved my problem.